# Android Gridview not working

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I wrote a code for android grid view, but unfortunately when i run the code Application returns error like this "The Appication Nues Hound RSS(process com.nues.rss) has stoped unexpectedly Please try agian later"

If anyone knows how to solve this please help out me. I cant find any coding error. So experts are welcome to give proper instructions.

This is my activity class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (!isNetworkAvailbale()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet Connection not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gridview);

    GridView gridView;

    ImageAdapter mAdapter;

    mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {@
        Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > arg0, View arg1, int position, long

            arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(NuesHoundRSSActivity.this, "Item co" + osition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

This is the adapter class

```
package com.nues.rss;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;  

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {

}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

   // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public static class ViewHolder  
{  
    public ImageView imgView;    
}  

@Override  
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    ViewHolder view;  
    LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();  

    if(convertView==null)  
    {  
        view = new ViewHolder();  
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gridview_row, null);  

        view.imgView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  

        convertView.setTag(view);  

    }  
    else  
    {  
        view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
    }  

    view.imgView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);  

    return convertView;  
}  

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};


}
```

This is my Gridview XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="5dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: When your app crash, what is your log from the LogCat? What exception? What line?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException at ImageAdapter class line 40 which is "LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();" , do you have any idea ? I'm using Android platform 2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private Activity activity;  

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {

}
```

replace this with the following

```
private Context c;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            this.c = c;

        }
```

And

```
LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();
```

with

```
LayoutInflater inflator = ((Activity) c).getLayoutInflater();
```

this will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

see here:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Activity activity;  

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {

    }
```

you are not initialize your activity object.

try this:

```
 public ImageAdapter(Activity ac) {
    this.activity=ac;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mate your solution also correct, but i cannot accept more than one answer... :(

Answer (score 0):

In your code `private Activity activity;` is never set to anything and is null, so `activity.getLayoutInflater();` crashes.

You want to do something like this:

```
private Context context; 

public ImageAdapter(Context c) { 
    this.context = c;
}
```

And then `context.getLayoutInflater();`.

Comment: Thanks mate your solution also correct, but i cannot accept more than one answer... :(